# Repository Interface(s) in Domain-Driven Design

Tags: interface, domain-driven-design, dns, repository

Regarding the contract between the domain and repository, I gather it's best to avoid an all-encompassing generic IRepository interface with methods such as Create() and Delete()?  Unless, of course, it's natural to have these methods available for all the entities I'm working with.  Which I imagine is a rare scenario.

Instead, should I create a basic IRepository contract with as many - perhaps "as few" would be more appropriate - common methods (e.g., GetByID()) as makes sense?  All repositories could implement the contract and then specialize.

Or is it better to go the route of multiple specialized interfaces, à la ICreatable, IDeletable, IRetrievable, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should only create an basic IRepository if the methods within the interface are used by **all** repositories. If you have some repositories that will implement only a part of the methods, than you should go for the more specialized interfaces.

Also the last option will give you more flexibility in adding behaviour later to your repository when needed. If you use the basic IRepository interface and have to add a new method to it, than you will have to update all repositories. If you use the specialized version than you only have to update the repositories to which you want to apply this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Generic interfaces are useless, especially in DDD, because they hide otherwise explicit concepts. Imagine your command handler / application service constructor:

```
public SomeCommandHandler(IRepository customerRepository, IRepository userRepository)
```

and compare to this:

```
public SomeCommandHandler(ICustomerRepository customerRepository, IUserRepository userRepository)
```

The latter is far more explicit and explicitness is what you seek by doing DDD. Moreover, if your repositories have all the same methods, you are probably creating a CRUD data access layer which usually doesn't fit well with DDD.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use GenericRepository and Specification pattern. This is save you from making a lot of specialized methods in each repository.

Comment: The Specification pattern is only for querying, right?  If we're talking other functionality such as Create() and Delete(), a generic repository that defines these methods suggests they should be available for all entities.  Probably not a good thing in most cases.

Comment: not a good idea of ​​the availability of methods Create and Delete? or what?

Comment: Right.  In an e-commerce domain you should be able to delete a ShoppingCartItem but not a placed Order.

Comment: I don't understand how it's due to Repository? Or do you mean abstraction level? 
In your case you have 2 Aggregation Roots: ShoppingCartItem and Order, and you have 2 Repositories or one generic repository, it does not matter.
You should not call delete method for Order. And that all.

Comment: I like a design in which Delete() not only should not be called for Order, but actually cannot be called because it isn't made available.  This is possible only with two separate repositories.  If I use a single generic repository, it would expose Delete() for all entities, regardless of whether Delete() makes sense for Order or not.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But other developer whatever can write code in any part of program, which will delete your entity bypass your repository.

Comment: Good design is all we can offer.  We make no guarantees against cowboy coders.  ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Gengzu.
I've used this approach in several projects and in my role as a solution architect I want all developers in the team only write necessary and specific code.
My experience is that you most of the times want a Delete and Find method etc. The cases where you don't want this shouldn't dictate. Consequences will be that the repositories that need Delete will all have to implement this and this will be redundant code. All these Delete methods could instead have been implemented By a GenericRepository abstract class. That class can work against NHibernate and take a generic entity as T. When you then want to create for example a UserRepository it will inherit from GenericRepository and IUserRepository.
Where IUserRepository inherit from IRepository. I will add some code:

```
    public class UserRepository : GenericNHibernateRepository<User, int>, IUserRepository
        {
            #region IUserRepository Members


            public User GetUserByEmail(string email)
            {
                ICriterion[] query = {Restrictions.Eq("Email", email)};

                var list = GetByCriteria(query);

                if (list.Count == 0)

                    return null;
                else
                    return list[0];
            }

            #endregion
        }


    public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User, int>
        {
            User GetUserByEmail(string email);
        }

 public interface IRepository<T, ID> where T : IAggregateRoot
    {
        T GetById(ID id);
        List<T> GetAll();
        T Save(T entity);
        T SaveOrUpdate(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Flush();
}
```

So what re the benefits. There are huge! 
As you can see for IRepository interface we only allow IAggregateRoot to have a repository (a DDD guideline).
All repositories delete's will be named Delete (no developer will name it Remove etc. and its only implementen at one place, the GenericNHibernate class).
If a developer in my team want to create a new repository for an entity the only code is

public class CustomerRepositoryNHibernate : GenericNHibernateRepository, ICustomerRepository {}

Then you get read, delete, find functiuons... you name it. Not Bad.

But another superb benefit if your using Dependency Injection and IoC framework I can just say that with for example Windsor Castle you can create a facility that loads all repositories that implement the IRepository interface and are located in a assemebly (example MyProject.Infrastructure.Data). This gives you extremly boost for your team.

First you developer creates a new repository in MyProject.Infrastructure.Data with on line of code like the example above.

Second at application startup Windsor Castle facility will make it available for injection.
So your developer can just continue writing a controller or service class that takes
IComnpanyRepository as constructor parameter and its all there.

Comment: For reuse there's no doubt a generic repository's better.  Still, to me something's off with the fact that the contract between the domain and the repository doesn't reflect the business intentions of the domain.

Comment: Well you always strip the IRepository interface from methods. But my repository interfaces (contracts...) used by the domain are very descriptive and visual what they are doing. look at IUserRepository above with method GetUserByEmail. Usually you get specific methods for each repository. But When it comes to Delete or Load or Get they all do the same, operate on one entity instance.

Comment: I prefer the @S.Valmont approach.  Repository thinking is about reduction in lines of code.  It usually prevents proper DDD thinking.  Your data access only needs to satisfy the actions your domain performs, and the queries the domain needs to make.  

I've spent much time trying to write gorgeous polymorphic repositories, only to belated realise my domain only actually does a couple of things! 
Also, if you're dealing in very large numbers of records, it's unlikely a repository or any ORM approach will suffice.